# Drupal 9: Which CSS stylesheets control the contents of articles and the front page?

Tags: drupal-9

I want to tweak the fonts of the Drupal default theme ›Bartik‹, namely I need to have sans-serif headings in articles (and preferrably on the front page).

The theme *does* recognise headings, as they are larger than body text, but I don't find the CSS-stylesheet ruling the articles' fonts.

The page source yields some 100 CSS stylesheets, which either have nothing to with fonts according to their filename or don't have any effect on the fonts, although they seem to.

Diving into the directory tree brinds up about 760 CSS stylesheets – and I'm completely lost.

I do *not* want to create a subtheme (at least not now), as I would end up with the same problem: Not to know, which CSS I would have to tweak or apply.

Any hint would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<drupalroot>/core/themes/<theme>/css/base/elements.css
```

eventually worked for me – after I realised that an active cache would prevent delivery of edited settings and thus making me believe, changes would yield no effect.